# Image changing on same slide results in "image shifting"

Tags: tables, beamer

To have text and images on the same slide, I use this kind of code:

```
\frametitle{My title}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\onslide<2->{\item Item 1}
\onslide<3->{\item Item 2}
\end{itemize}}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\only<2>{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Image1}}
\only<3>{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{Image2}}
\end{tabular}
```

I'm pretty happy with the output, except for this small detail: even if Image1 and Image2 are the same dimensions in pixels, Image2 is slightly shifted to the right compared to Image1. Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Damn, as soon as I posted this, I found a solution: no linebreak between the two \only and the problem is solved. Sorry guys

Comment: Or just a comment `%` character after the `\only`s

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the authors find a solution

Comment: @RomainPicot Why should it be closed? It is a valid question and probably helpful for other LaTeX beginners. I think it should be answered properly with a short explanation why this happens and a link to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Comment: The original poster can always delete it if he wants to.

Comment: The "% at the end of the line solution" is perfect, thanks !